# How to call function in Javascript when window is getting resized

Tags: javascript

How can i call a simple function in Javascript, for example:

```
function doSmt() {
   alert("hello world")
}
```

whenever the user is going to resize the window in any way. So if he for example just resize it with the mouse, or if he zoom into or out the website.

I already tried:

```
window.onresize = doSmt()
```

as it stands on some websites, but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two ways:

The first one is almost the same as you already have, but you're calling the function instead of binding it:

```
window.onresize = doSmt;
```

The second way allows you to get the event as well:

```
window.onresize = function ( event ) {
    doSmt();
}
```

## Extra

User [Silviu Burcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051677/silviu-burcea) added the useful information that when your `doSmt` function accepts parameters it can also use the `event` parameter:

```
function doSmt(event) {
    alert("Hello world");
}

window.onresize = doSmt;
```

Comment: If your function, e.g `doSmt`, has an event parameter, you can catch the event anyway: `const doSmt = (evt) => { ... }; window.onresize = doSmt;`

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Thanks, added that information, be it in the style of the question posted.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the function itself, not call it:

`window.onresize = doSet;`